# Cannot get data from PHP API with JS fetch although status code is 200

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to get data from a PHP API with following script:

```js
const url = "http://.../test/test_php_api/api.php";
const queryData = { command: "readUser", email: "john.doe@mailbox.com" }
const body = JSON.stringify(queryData);

var request = new Request(url, {
    'method': 'POST',
    'body': body,
    'headers': {
        'Accept': 'application/json', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});
fetch(request)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Response Status", response.status);
        console.log("Response Status Text", response.headers);
        return response.text();
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log("result", result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error); // Handle any errors
    });
```

The return code is 200 but there is no data.
I checked the API and found out the $_POST is empty. So something must be wrong with my JS request.
I tested the API with HTML FORM and it's working fine.
Any suggestions what I could do?
I want to add that also `file_get_contents('php://input');` is empty.

Comment: The PHP endpoint works using standard POST data (like an HTML form) but you are sending JSON data.

Comment: I thought that the method 'POST' sends POST data too. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Yes, but we're talking about the format here: using an HTML form will send data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, sending the data as a query string in the request body and is automatically mapped to `$_POST`. If you really want to send JSON, check the question pinned on top of yours.

Comment: Okay, problem solved. I get the data with `$data = file_get_contents('php://input');`.
Thank you AymDev.